# TIKZ - changing one block into parallel multiple blocks

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-arrows, tikz-trees, tikz-node

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[crop,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows,
    chains,
    decorations.markings,
    shadows, shapes.arrows,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[start chain = going below,
  every node/.append style={on chain,fill opacity=0.8,draw,
  join},every join/.style={thick,-latex},
  cs/.style={minimum width=4.5cm,copy shadow={shadow scale=1, shadow xshift=0.5ex, shadow yshift=-0.5ex}}
  ]

 \node[fill=white] (N1) {\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}cp{1cm}}
    IOH\\
    & \enspace\tiny $K\times K$\quad\quad \quad & 
    \end{tabular}};

 \node[fill=orange] (N2) {\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}cp{1cm}}
    COI\\
    \qquad\enspace\tiny\quad\quad\quad\quad $K\times K$ 
      \end{tabular}};

 \node[fill=white] (N3) {\begin{tabular}{p{4cm}cp{4cm}}
    \qquad
    \end{tabular}};

 \node[fill=white] (N4) {\begin{tabular}{p{1cm}cp{1cm}}
   GOH &\\
   & \tiny $K\times K$ \enspace\enspace& 
  \end{tabular}};
\end{scope}  
 \path (N1) -- (N2) coordinate[pos=0.5] (aux);
 \path (N2) -- (N3) node[pos=0.5,right,font=\bfseries\itshape]{};
 \path (N3) -- (N4) node[pos=0.5,right,font=\bfseries\itshape]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which produces the following figure:
[image]

Now I want to change this code in order to get the new figure:
[image]

Note that above the character 'N' appears an underbrace.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% has to be after decorations.pathreplacings
                }
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm and 7mm,
 start chain = going below,
  box/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum size=2em},
box/.default = white,
every edge/.style = {draw, -Latex},
   BC/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt,
                raise=1mm},
                very thick, pen colour=#1
                }
                    ]
    \begin{scope}[every node/.append style={on chain}]
\node (N1) [box]
            {\begin{tabular}{p{12mm} >{\tiny}c p{12mm}}
                 IOH    &               &   \\
                        & $K\times K$   &
            \end{tabular}};
\node (N2) [box=orange]
            {\begin{tabular}{p{12mm} >{\tiny}c p{12mm}}
                 COI    &               &   \\
                        & $K\times K$   &
            \end{tabular}};
\node (N3) [box, node font=\bfseries]  {A};
    \end{scope}
\node (N4) [box,below=11mm of N3]
            {\begin{tabular}{p{12mm} >{\tiny}c p{12mm}}
                 GOH    &               &   \\
                        & $K\times K$   &
            \end{tabular}};
\node (N3L) [box, node font=\bfseries, left=of N3] {A};
\node (N3R) [box, node font=\bfseries,right=of N3] {A};
%
\path   (N1) edge (N2)
        (N2) edge (N3)
        (N2) edge (N3L.north)
        (N2) edge (N3R.north);
\draw[BC]   (N3R.south east) -- node (aux) [below=2mm] {$N$} (N3L.south west);
\path[shorten >=1pt]    (aux -| N3L) edge (N4)
                        (aux)        edge (N4)
                        (aux -| N3R) edge (N4);
\draw[ultra thick, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm, dotted]
        (N3L) edge[-]  (N3)
        (N3R) edge[-]  (N3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*Note*: from your MWE I remove all not used TikZ libraries and defined style and add `arrows.meta` (for arrows head), and `decorations.pathreplacing` and `calligraphy` for brace under nodes with text "A".

Answer (score 3):

This is a little variation on Zarko's excellent code.

Node's contents are defined as `labels` instead of `tabulars`. This way, node's size must be declared.

Positions are defined with `positioning` library and no `chains` are used.

Nodes in third row are declared with a `matrix` node.

All edges are drawn using Zarko's code adapted to new names for third row nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                decorations.pathreplacing,
                calligraphy,% had to be after lib. decorations.pathreplacings
                matrix,
                positioning
                }
\usepackage{textcomp}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 5mm,
    box/.style = {draw, fill=#1, minimum height=1cm, minimum width=4.5cm},
    box/.default = white,
    every edge/.style = {draw, -Latex},
   BC/.style = {decorate,
                decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=5pt,
                raise=1mm},
                very thick, pen colour=#1
                }
                    ]
 \node (N1) [box, label={[anchor=north west]north west:IOH},
                label={[anchor=south, font=\tiny]south:$K\times K$}]
            {};                   
 \node (N2) [box=orange, label={[anchor=north west]north west:COI},
                label={[anchor=south, font=\tiny]south:$K\times K$},
                below=of N1]
            {};
 \matrix (N3) [matrix of nodes, inner sep=0pt, nodes={minimum size=1cm, draw, anchor=center, node font=\bfseries, node contents=A}, nodes in empty cells, column sep=.5cm,
        below=of N2]{&&\\};
  \node (N4) [box, label={[anchor=north west]north west:GOH},
                label={[anchor=south, font=\tiny]south:$K\times K$},
                below=1cm of N3]
            {};
\path   (N1) edge (N2)
        (N2) edge (N3-1-1.north)
        (N2) edge (N3-1-2)
        (N2) edge (N3-1-3.north);
\draw[BC]   (N3.south east) -- node (aux) [below=2mm] {$N$} (N3.south west);
\path[shorten >=1pt]    (aux -| N3-1-1) edge (N4)
                        (aux)        edge (N4)
                        (aux -| N3-1-3) edge (N4);
\draw[ultra thick, shorten <=1mm, shorten >=1mm, dotted]
        (N3-1-1) edge[-]  (N3-1-2)
        (N3-1-2) edge[-]  (N3-1-3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: nice answer (+1)! somewhere in my remembrance i had your solutions for labels inside nodes which you probably show in some my question ;-)

Comment: @Codevan, in distance between nodes. in my answer are for one dot more apart.